Is sheafification required on the distinguished affine base for constructions involving quasicoherent sheaves?
Let $X$ be a scheme. By distinguished affine base I mean subsets $U\subseteq X$ isomorphic to $\mathrm{Spec}{\, A}$ for some ring $A$ along with the data of all open inclusions $V\hookrightarrow U$ where $V\cong\mathrm{Spec}{\, A_f}$ for some $f\in A$.
Given some sheaves $\mathscr{F}_{\alpha}$ on $X$ we may "construct" another sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ on $X$ by defining it as the sheafification of some presheaf obtained from the $\mathscr{F}_{\alpha}$. For instance, if $\mathscr{F}_1$ and $\mathscr{F}_2$ are $\mathscr{O}_X$-modules, then we may define $\mathscr{F}_1\otimes\mathscr{F}_2$ to be the sheafification of the presheaf $U\mapsto\mathscr{F}_1(U)\otimes_{\mathscr{O}_X(U)}\mathscr{F}_2(U)$.
But if $\mathscr{F}_1$ and $\mathscr{F}_2$ are quasicoherent, this sheafification is redundant at least on the distinguished affine open subsets; for if $U\subseteq X$ is affine, then $(\mathscr{F}_1\otimes\mathscr{F}_2)(U)\cong\mathscr{F}_1(U)\otimes_{\mathscr{O}_X(U)}\mathscr{F}_2(U)$. This is stated in Vakil's FOAG Exercise 6.2.F. Vakil goes on to state:

Note that thanks to the machinery behind the distinguished affine base, sheafification is taken care of. This is a feature we will use often: constructions involving
quasicoherent sheaves that involve sheafification for general sheaves don’t require
sheafification when considered on the distinguished affine base.

My question is: why is this true? Is Vakil appealing to some general principle here or is this just something that needs to be checked for each construction one may make with quasicoherent sheaves? If there is a general principle at play, I would like to see it stated precisely. In particular, I am interested in understanding why $\det{\mathscr{F}}=\bigwedge^n{\mathscr{F}}$ has the "obvious" ring of sections $\bigwedge^n{\mathscr{F}(U)}$ over affine subsets $U$ when $\mathscr{F}$ is locally free, instead of something more complicated as is typical of sheafification.

This is the content of section 2.5 in the book, "Recovering sheaves from a 'sheaf on a base'." Have you read that section of the text?

@KReiser yes I have read that section. I'm just having trouble seeing how that is being used. In the case of the tensor product of sheaves for example, we construct it as a sheafification of a presheaf. It appears that we could instead define it as the "obvious thing" on affine opens and then use section 2.5 to extend the sheaf on the base to the whole space. My question is why can we do the latter when the former is taken to be the definition? It is not obvious to me that the sheafification of the presheaf should agree with the induced sheaf from the "obvious" sheaf on the base.

The construction induced from the distinguished base gives a sheaf (this is what is proven in the earlier section). By the universal property of sheafification, there is a map from the sheafification to the sheaf built from the distinguished base. That map is an isomorphism on stalks.

@JakeLevinson this reasoning requires knowing a priori that our sheafified presheaf agrees with the distinguished base sheaf on the distinguished base, right? My question is essentially asking why this agreement is automatic as Vakil claims.

I don't think so? Let $F^\mathrm{pre}$ be a presheaf, which is moreover a sheaf on the base. Let $F^\mathrm{dist}$ be the sheaf constructed from the distinguished base. Let $G$ be any sheaf on $X$ and $F^\mathrm{pre} \to G$ a map. By Vakil 2.5.C, this gives a unique map $F^\mathrm{dist} \to G$. This is the universal property of sheafification, so $F^\mathrm{dist} \cong F^\mathrm{sh}$.

@JakeLevinson I almost follow except that $F^{\mathrm{pre}}$ is a presheaf and 2.5.C appears to only apply to morphisms of sheaves. We only know that $F^{\mathrm{pre}}$ agrees with $F^{\mathrm{dist}}$ on the distinguished base, and we would like to apply 2.5.C to the sheafification $(F^{\mathrm{pre}})^{\mathrm{sh}}$, but I am not sure that $(F^{\mathrm{pre}})^{\mathrm{sh}}$ agrees with $F^{\mathrm{dist}}$ on the distinguished base.
